# Telegram max number of Admin bots in channel

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

As of now, it seems that Telegram API does not allow bots to be added to channels as normal subscribers, thus only way to add them is as Administrators.

Is there a **maximum number** of bots that can be added to a single Channel as Administrators due to the above limitation?

Answer (score 0):

Groups bots limited to **20**. channel maybe too.